# how to make pie charts with percentages for multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pie-chart

I want to have multiple pie charts per column and across two groups.

My data looks like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(ID, age, gender, diagnosis, A1, A2, A3)
mydf
ID age gender diagnosis A1 A2 A3
a  22 female         1  A  D  B
b  34   male         2  B  E  NA
c  55 female         2  C  B  A
d  55 female         1  NA A  B
e  45   male         1  E  D  B
```

here A1, A2, and A3 refer to the questions in the test I applied to participants and the letters below represent the answer chosen by the participant. So, it is a categorical value.
Diagnosis 1 and 2 refer to whether the participant is diagnosed or not with the illness.

I want to calculate the percentage-wise frequencies for each question(omitting NA values) and make a pie chart by diagnosis. Is there any code you can think of that would provide me with multiple pie charts at one go or should I write a separate code for each question(I have so many questions, that's why I am asking? :D)

So, in the end, I would like to have pie charts like this next to each other for each question:

[image: representative pie chart]

Thank you so much!

Comment: See this first: https://blog.livealytics.com/why-pie-charts-suck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- tribble(
  ~ID, ~age, ~gender, ~diagnosis, ~A1, ~A2, ~A3,
  "a",  22, "female",         1,  "A",  "D",  "B",
  "b",  34,   "male",         2,  "B",  "E",  NA,
  "c",  55, "female",         2,  "C",  "B",  "A",
  "d",  55, "female",         1,  NA, "A",  "B",
  "e",  45,   "male",         1,  "E",  "D",  "B",
)
```

Pivot the data and calculate percentages using the `table()` and `prop.table()`. The factor is used so we can keep all the options.

```
mydf_ <- mydf |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A1, A2, A3), names_to = "question", values_to = "answer") |> 
  group_by(diagnosis, question) |> 
  mutate(answer = factor(answer, levels = c("A", "B","C", "D", "E"))) |> 
  summarise(percentage = c(prop.table(table(answer)))) |> 
  mutate(answer = c("A", "B","C", "D", "E"))
```

Create the pie chart using `geom_bar()`, `geom_text()` and `coord_polar()`:

```
mydf_ |> 
  mutate(percentage = ifelse(percentage == 0, NA, percentage)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = percentage, 
             fill = answer, 
             label = scales::percent(percentage))) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(color = "white", size=6, 
              position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_polar("y") +
    facet_grid(diagnosis ~ question, switch = "both") +
    labs(x = "Diagnosis", y = "Questions") +
    theme(axis.text  = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank()
         )
```

Result:

[image: Pie chart]

Comment: Dear @Vlad, this code gave me what I wanted and I thank you so much! However, the percentage calculation gives numbers like 37.714% or 60.000% . I tried to round but then it caused errors or again gave numbers like 60.0% . why it might be the case?

Comment: oh I found a way! it worked when i included this code in ggplot :   geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percentage*100), "%")), color = "white", size=3, 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))

Comment: That should work. Another way of rounding it is to use the `accuracy` option in the `scales::percent()` function.